# front-page.php stylesheet

Tags: css, frontpage

I've googled and googled but I can't seem to find out anything that's understandable to me...

I want to have a static front page for my website, to this end I have created a `front-page.php` file in the active theme's folder in my FTP server. I notice any edits I do in `style.css` are not reflected in `front-page.php`. I want to have a separate stylesheet for my front page anyway, so how do I go about linking `front-page.php` to a custom `.css` file, let's say, `front-style.css`, so I can just edit the `.css` file to style the `.php` file? Or isn't this the right approach?

Comment: Edits to `style.css` *should* be reflected in your front page, unless you're already loading a custom stylesheet.

Answer (score 3):

## How to load a custom stylesheet for your Front Page

1. Set up `front-page.php` (which you've done already).
2. Create a stylesheet for your front page (you can copy `style.css`, but more likely, you'll just want to override a few things).  Let's call it `front-page-style.css`.
3. View the HTML source of one of your pages, and find the `id` of the `style.css` file (probably something along the lines of `your-theme-css`)  Trimming the `-css` part will tell us what we need to use as a *dependency* in the code.
4. Add the following to your theme's `functions.php` file:

   ```
   add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse102732_front_page_styles', 20 );
   function wpse102732_front_page_styles() {
       if( is_front_page() ) {
           // Any dependencies go here:
           // if the style.css id in step 3 was 'your-theme-css',
           // then use 'your-theme'
           $deps = array( 'your-theme' );
           $handle = 'your-theme-front-page';
           $url = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/front-page-style.css';
           wp_enqueue_style( $handle, $url, $deps );
       }
   }
   ```

You should now be able to modify styles in `front-page-style.css` for just the front page.

#### References

- [`wp_enqueue_style()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style)
- [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri)